# Trouble matching SHA512 hash from PHP with C# counterpart formula

Tags: c#, php, hash

This should be so simple but I've spent 4 hours fiddling with this code and I just can't seem to get it to work.

The PHP code works as follows (I didn't write it and I can't change it, so I'm stuck with it):

```
$password = hash('sha512', "HelloWorld1");
$salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true);
$hashed = hash('sha512', $password.$salt);
```

$hashed and $salt are stored in the DB as is. That means $salt is already hashed for later on.

I have no idea why they decided to hash *everything* but what's done is done.

In this case, the result is

```
Pswd: ab3e648d69a71b33d0420fc3bfc9e2e8e3ef2a300385ea26bc22057a84cd9a5c359bd15c4a0a552122309e58938ce310839cd9d2ecad5f294266015d823331dd
Salt: fb5a0f741db0be2439dc14662aae3fc68eb5e16b446385d3ddd319b862d5e2d4f50488a39487b27fdd8ff7b7b76420fc3ebef2bce9e082ac15c9f2d6fe7d87fc
```

Now the login code on the C# side just needs to match a plain text hashed password along with the already hashed salt.

```
string password = "HelloWorld1";
string storedSalt = "fb5a0f741db0be2439dc14662aae3fc68eb5e16b446385d3ddd319b862d5e2d4f50488a39487b27fdd8ff7b7b76420fc3ebef2bce9e082ac15c9f2d6fe7d87fc";

using(SHA512 shaManaged = new SHA512Managed())
{
    byte[] hashPassword = shaManaged.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
    string hashPasswordString = BitConverter.ToString(hashPassword).Replace("-", "");
    byte[] finalHash = shaManaged.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashPasswordString + storedSalt));

    Debug.WriteLine("Calculated Hash Password: " + BitConverter.ToString(finalHash).Replace("-", ""));
}
```

Essentially the idea is to

1. Hash the plain text password first (same as with the PHP code).
2. Convert the byte array to a string that matches the PHP format of hashing.
3. Then hash the hashed password and previously hashed salt together.

The result is as follows:

```
    Stored Hash Password: AB3E648D69A71B33D0420FC3BFC9E2E8E3EF2A300385EA26BC22057A84CD9A5C359BD15C4A0A552122309E58938CE310839CD9D2ECAD5F294266015D823331DD
Calculated Hash Password: 189ABBA71AAEDDE5C8154558B68D59500A72E64D5F3F3C07EFA94F0126571FBB68C6ADD105E0C029BABF30CADD8A6A6B6E4749075854461A88EE1CE545E84507
```

Hopefully someone can spot where I'm going wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tweak your code a little bit. Note the `ToLowerInvariant()`. C# returns upper case letters as string. As you see in your original code `$salt` and `$password` are returned with lower case letters, so your self calculated password hash `hashPasswordString` must also be lower case before concatenating with your `storedSalt` to gain the correct `finalHash`. Your shown expected result again uses upper case letters (maybe before stored it was converted in PHP?) so you don't need `ToLowerCaseInvariant()` on your final hash string.

Here is the code:

```
string password = "HelloWorld1";
string storedSalt = "fb5a0f741db0be2439dc14662aae3fc68eb5e16b446385d3ddd319b862d5e2d4f50488a39487b27fdd8ff7b7b76420fc3ebef2bce9e082ac15c9f2d6fe7d87fc";

using (SHA512 shaManaged = new SHA512Managed())
{
    byte[] hashPassword = shaManaged.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
    string hashPasswordString = BitConverter.ToString(hashPassword).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant(); // Note the ToLowerInvariant();
    byte[] finalHash = shaManaged.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashPasswordString + storedSalt));

    return BitConverter.ToString(finalHash).Replace("-", "");
}
```

Comment: You're amazing. Thank you so much for helping me out. I can't believe it was something so minor. Good catch!